# how to use Keychain in Ionic hybrid mobile app

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to mobile development and need support for using the Keychain in my app, can you please help me with how to add keychain plugin and how to use it..

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project and add this plugin

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/shazron/KeychainPlugin.git`

And in your controller do this

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaKeychain) {

  $scope.getValueFromKey = function(key) {
    $cordovaKeychain.getForKey(key, servicename).then(function(value) {
      console.log(value);
    }, function (err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  };

});
```

Take a look at [cordovakeychain](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/keychain/) plugin and [Git-hub](https://github.com/shazron/KeychainPlugin) for using it.

Comment: cordova plugin add https://github.com/shazron/KeychainPlugin.git  ....... this command is not working

Comment: Worked for me.  Verify that you are using the latest cordova & ionic